# Auto format parameters one per line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-7.1

When I was using Visual Studio 2010 with an old version of Resharper (I was fairly new to Resharper then), I used to have an option that came up that allowed it to auto format parameters of a method to one per line when the parameters were not all on one line. Therefore, if there were a few parameters all on one line, in order to get them one per line, I would move the first one to a separate line which would then give me the option to format one per line. However, this option has since disappeared. I am now using Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper 7.1. I'm not sure what caused it but does anyone know how I can bring back the option?

TIA

Comment: I understand the intent of this question. May I ask why you choose to have code with each parameter in its own line? Doesn't doing so, make it difficult to read code? Are you having a lot of parameters? Are the parameter names really long? Is your screen not wide enough (in which case, it may not even be tall enough to see more code per screen)?  Is this really a good style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check you have the following settings set up here `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Line Wrapping:`

1. Wrap formal parameters -> Chop always;
2. Prefer wrap after "(" in declaration -> ticked;